# Where i wants to give the actual keyword in my website for SEO?

Tags: seo, magento-1.7, google-search

I have 10 keywords for my website. Please tell Where i wants to give the actual keyword in my website (home page or any place?)for display google search?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 4):

For put keywords in Home Page or any other Page:
Login to Admin panel.
go to **CMS->Pages** than select any page.
Here in `Mete Data` tab you can insert your Meta Keywords and Meta Description.

For put keyword in Category page:
go to **Catalog->Manage Categories** than select any category.
Here you can insert your Meta Keywords and Meta Description.

For put keyword in Product Detail page:
goto **Catalog->Manage Products** than select any product.
Here in `Meta Information` tab insert your Meta Title,Meta Keywords and Meta Description.
(If not display `Meta Information` tab or meta attributes than goto **Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes Set** to manage meta attribues for product accoring to product type.)

Answer (score -1):

u should put those in meta tag

`<meta name="description" content="Awesome Description Here">`

of your page

Answer (score -1):

you should add these meta tags in header of all pages.

```
 <meta name="title" content="TITLE of Page">
 <meta name="description" content="Description of Page">
 <meta name="keywords" content="title,tag,tag2">
```

avoid repeating the keywords